# Microsoft Web Deployment Tool: "Only absolute paths are supported"

Tags: iis, migration, metabase

I get the following error when I try to use the Web Deployment Tool and a URL is the path of a virtual directory:

C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy>msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm/w3svc -dest:archivedir=c:\archive,encryptPassword=mypassword > msdeployachive.log

Error: File system path 'http://mysite.com/nnn' is not valid. Only absolute paths are supported.
Error count: 1.

This appears to be the part of the metabase (IIS 6) it is complaining about:

```
<IIsWebVirtualDir   Location ="/LM/W3SVC/9999999999/root/stuff"
        AccessFlags="AccessRead"
        AppFriendlyName="stuff"
        HttpRedirect="http://mysite.com/nnn"
        Path="http://mysite.com/nnn"
    >
</IIsWebVirtualDir>
```

Unfortunately there are hundreds of virtual directories like this with a URL as the path.

Anyone know of a solution or a good alternative for migrating hundreds of sites from IIS 6 to IIS 7?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to run like this:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=lm/w3svc,filePath.ignoreErrors=0x8000020;0x80070005 -skip:attributes.value="http:/mysite.com/.*$" -dest:archivedir=c:\archive,encryptPassword=mypassword -verbose -debug > msdeployarchive.log
```